# Create a HIVE table and save it to a tab-separated file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have some data in hdfs.
This data was migrated from a PostgreSQL database by using Sqoop.
The data has the following hadoopish format, like `_SUCCESS`, `part-m-00000`, etc.
I need to create a Hive table based on this data and then I need to export this table to a single tab-separated file.

As far as I know, I can create a table this way.

```
create external table table_name (
  id int,
  myfields string
)
location '/my/location/in/hdfs';
```

Then I can save the table as `tsv` file:

```
hive -e 'select * from some_table' > /home/myfile.tsv
```

I don't know how to load data from hdfs into a Hive table.
Moreover, should I manually define the structure of a table using `create` or is there any automated way when all columns are created automatically?

Comment: Hive data is already in HDFS at LOCATION

Comment: What sqoop command did you use? It has options to create Hive tables for you

Comment: @cricket_007: This was done by another people. So, I cannot change this.

Comment: Okay, then you should go talk to those people, or else you have to manually write your `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` query... Those are the only options I see. The automated way is the first one

Comment: The title of the question is pretty misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to load data from hdfs into Hive table

You create a table schema over a hdfs directory like you're doing.

> should I manually define the structure of a table using create or is there any automated way when all columns are created automatically?

Unless you didn't [tell sqoop to create the table](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive), you must do it manually.

> export this table into a single tab-separated file.

A query might work, or unless sqoop set the delimiter to `\t`, then you need to create another table from the first specifying such column separator. And then, you don't even need to query the table, just run `hdfs dfs -getMerge` on the directory